# Make a MATLAB function explicit

Tags: matlab, explicit, function-handle

I am using a toolbox in MATLAB and I'm not ready to make any change to the functions within it.

Let's say that it has a function `f = @(x,l) g(x)*h(l)`

I want to call `f` at different `x` but always the same `l`:

```
l = 3;
f2(x) = @(x) f(x,l);
```

```
for i=1:length(x)
   f2(x(i));
end
```

However, if I do this, the function `h` will be called at `l=3` for each `i`. I would like MATLAB to know when I defined `f2` that `h(l)` can be stored and that actually `f2(x) = 3*g(x)`
Is there a way around this problem ? or do I need to go into the code of  `f2` and write somewhere:

```
A = h(l);
f2 = @(x) A*g(x)
```

Comment: Your last sentence is the answer to your question. The value of `A` will be statically stored in the workspace of `f2()` at the time you define your function `f2 = @(x) A*g(x)`.

Comment: Yes but i would need to look where in the toolbox there is `f(x,l) = g(x)*h(l)` and as i said, I'm not willing to change anything in the toolbox as there might be multiple times where it is more suitable to store the function output than calling it everytime.

Comment: you don't need to change anything in the toolbox itself. You just need to look at it to identify `g(x)` and `h(l)`. Once it is done, calculate `A=h(3);`, then overload the toolbox function `f()` with your own new definition of `f = @(x) A*g(x)`

Comment: Yes, it would work, the thing is that i don't want to look for the exact line where `f` is defined. Instead, i am looking for a generic way to make sure when i am calling a function `f2 = @(x)f(x,l)` , that sub-functions within `f` that depend only on `l` are stored to optimize CPU time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not define your function as?

```
f2 = @(x) f(x,3)
```

Comment: If it do it this way, MATLAB won't store `h(3)` but will call `h` everytime i call `f2` at a new `x`.

Comment: Yes, if that's what you want to prevent I don't see any workaround other than redefining the referred function.  What you want is *memoization* on the second argument.

Comment: @LudoM Related to karakfa comment above, see https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/memoize.html